# How do I install alipy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm on a jupyter lab instance and I'd like to install the alipy library.

I opened a terminal window and ran `pip install alipy` and got this error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-DWPPLN/alipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-DWPPLN/alipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-DWPPLN/alipy/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-DWPPLN/alipy/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.md', encoding='UTF-8').read(),
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have 2 versions of python (python 2 and python 3) installed and want to download the python 3 version of the module

`pip3 install alipy`

Comment: It does not work for python 2. You need to have at least python 3.4 installed for it to work. https://pypi.org/project/alipy/

Comment: I understand. How do I install alipy.metric?

Comment: You need to install alipy for that functionality. Or go to the projects github https://github.com/NUAA-AL/ALiPy and find the code you need. You will need to modify it slightly and convert it to python 2.

Comment: I have alipyinstalled for python 3. Should I be able to just access alipy.metric?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code and it works for python 3.7, maybe its because you are using python 2?

Comment: How do I install alipy.metric?

Comment: I imagine you can do "from alipy import metric" and then whenever you would call alipy.metric call just metric

Comment: also for me it says that alipy.metrics is the library not alipy.metric